# how to make a variable that count the number of orders in html/js and send it to GoogleSheet

Tags: javascript, html, variables, google-sheets, counter

I want to make a variable that counts how many orders that I got by calling a function. This variable must increment each time I get a new order. The problem with my code is that if the customer reloads the page or new customer orders a something, the variable returns to zero. I want the variable be incremented and not return to 0, the variable sends to google sheet not to database
please anyone help me out with this problem

```
    var i=0
function orderno(){
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();
    var orderno = "KKS-"+n+"-"+i++;
    document.getElementById("OrderNumber").value = orderno;
}
```

Comment: Why won’t you just save the variable in your database?

Comment: You need to save the information on some persisting server-side storage (be it a database or something simple as a text file) and to retrieve it from there.

Comment: because i don't have one right now

Answer (score 1):

### Issue:

You set your `var i` to 0 which automatically set the value of `i` to 0 every time the code get executed.

### Solution:

You can save your `orderno` to a spreadsheet, retrieve the latest `orderno`, parse the `orderno` to get the number/s after `KKS2020-XXXX` by using [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and assign it as initial value to `var i`. From there we can ensure that the value of `var i` is always the latest number in `orderno`.

### Further Reading

[Google Sheets API V4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js)